Debmirror - manage packages exclusion
I'm creating a mirror server for debian and ubuntu using debmirror and I would like to exclude all unnecessary packages such as aircrack-ng, firefox ... But I don't know all packages and their utility.
I know that we can exclude by category using "--exclude-deb-section=" but for example aircrack-ng and ssh are in the "net" category and I need ssh.
Is there a way to easily manage packages exclusion ? What are the best practices ?
